# HYH virus capturing Username & password from form authentication website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, asp-classic

One our customer complaint about HYH virus storing form authentication user credentials in clear text in his local system. Customer is accessing website through internet explorer. Is any preventing measure we can take in website or Code level?

More details on Website

1) Hosted in IIS 6.0

2) Windows Server 2003 Operating System

3) Written in ASP & ASP.net combination

Comment: Here You Have answer: Get the customer to remove the virus.

Comment: @jnpcl - no kidding. I can't count the number of times some customer wanted me to help with a vrius their system because they use their system to access our web site. I don't even like my friends asking me for free tech support. I couldn't imagine having to do it for all our customers. I have a hard enough time doing my part to keep our own site/server secure.

Comment: We said to customer, but he said the website should take care not storing username & password. It is difficult convey message to them. Is any best way to describing them? (ie.  telling them how virus effecting to his local system and not related to website. I tried to find out HYH virus architecture but no luck)

Comment: @user446573: The responsibility is entirely on your customer. If he refuses to clean the virus, he is an idiot.

Comment: to be productive, just answer 'yes, we have investigate and doublue check on our server and found some virus signature from client. please use anti-virus b4 its affect another client'. so now the customer will responsible for further incident :D and u dont have to do anything

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments above...

If *your* customer has a virus on **their** computer, then it's **their** problem.

If **they** don't want **their** usernames and passwords stored on **their** computer by the virus, then **they** need to get rid of it **themselves**.

The only thing I could recommend doing to get the point across would be to disable their account until they've cleaned the virus, since a compromised user can potentially lead to a compromised server.